# How to import pipeline.gocd.yaml from github repo to build gocd pipeline

Tags: cicd, go-cd

I'm quite new to go-cd. I have a **pipeline.gocd.yaml** in my git repo-in which i have defined my pipeline. Is there a way to I can import this into my go-cd server (through the agent) to build the pipeline.
I can't seem to find a way. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the config repository plugin which scans the repo for any *.gocd.yaml files and automatically creates the pipeline, groups, configuration etc.
https://github.com/tomzo/gocd-yaml-config-plugin